# Creating release using Octopus rest API

Tags: rest, octopus-deploy

Please can anybody explain me how to create release using Octopus REST API.
I can create a release using octo.exe but have no idea how to do that using REST API.
I went through the `http://localhost:8080/api`, but cant figure it out how to create a release.

Is this REST api providing that feature??

Comment: Yes, this is a RESTful API and they do provide an endpoint to create releases. Actually, they provide quite a lot of endpoints. However, most their documentation is not complete and nor do they provide an easy way to get started.

If you have the option to use their tools I would recommend doing so.

The tools can be found at https://octopus.com/downloads

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Octopus myself, but as far as I understand you have to make an HTTP POST request to an URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/projects/1/releases
```

In your request body you specify the same parameters as you would do it using the command line tool but you have to encode them as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar trouble with this myself.

In order to create a release, you must make a `POST` request to the Octo server.

https://myoctoserver:port/api/releases

Provide the following headers:

- X-Octopus-ApiKey: API-XXXXXXXXXXXX
- Content-Type: application/json

The body of the request must be `JSON`. Below is an example:

```
{
    "Version": "2017.02.25.183053" ,
    "ProjectId": "MyProject" ,
    "ChannelId": "DefaultOrOtherChannelId
}
```

The `Version` and `ProjectId` properties are required. Channel ID is optional. However, if you have more than one channel or if no channel in your project is marked as default then you must include `ChannelId` as well.

I hope this helps!

---

**Curl Example**

The sample below has been successful.

```
BODY='{"ProjectId":"'$PROJECT_ID'","ChannelId":"Channels-1","Version":"'$VERSION'","SelectedPackages":[{"StepName":"$STEP_NAME1","Version":"'$VERSION'"},{"StepName":"$STEP_NAME2","Version":"'$VERSION'"}]}'

curl -X POST --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null -H "X-Octopus-ApiKey:$API_KEY" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d $BODY "https://octopus.example.com/api/releases"
```

---

**Notes**

In order to find the `ChannelId` and `ProjectId` I had to query the Octopus database. The IDs will look something like `Projects-1` or `Channel-1`

Comment: This returns an error: No package version was specified for the step 'Get Package'. Their API documentation is really poor...

Comment: I have updated my post to include a curl example which I have used before. @mieliespoor The package is specified by both the version and the project ID. If you have a project _Foo_ with the version `0.5` then the json should look like `{"Version": "0.5", "ProjectId": "Foo", ChannelId: "Channels-1"}`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for interfacing with the Octopus REST API leaves a lot to be desired:
https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki/Releases

I could never get it working through this approach, instead, I use the [octo.exe command line utility to create releases](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Creating+releases):

```
octo create-release --project HelloWorld --version 1.0.3 --server http://octopus/ --apiKey API-ABCDEF123456
```

Octo.exe included as part of tentacle or server installs, Octopus also provide it as a seperate utility:
http://octopusdeploy.com/downloads